# Extract substring defined by start and end strings (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, substring

Given `std::wstring text`, `std::wstring start`, `std::wstring end`, the goal is to extract `std::wstring text_out` - containing text in between `start` and `end` - if they exist in `text`.

Note: if multiple matches to `start` exist - consider first one, for `end` - consider the last match.

This works, but is there more elegant solution?

```
boost::iterator_range<wstring::iterator> it_start = boost::find_first( text, start);
boost::iterator_range<wstring::iterator> it_end = boost::find_last( text, end);

if (it_start.empty() == false && it_end.empty() == false)
{
    text_out.assign( it_start.begin(), it_end.end() );
}
else if ( it_start.empty() == false && it_end.empty() == true )
{
    text_out.assign( it_start.begin(), text.end() );
}
else if ( it_start.empty() == true && it_end.empty() == false )
{
    text_out.assign( text.begin(), it_end.end() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any need to use boost. The same task can be done with using standard functions. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() 
{
    std::wstring text( L"startABCDEFend" );
    std::wstring start( L"start" );
    std::wstring end( L"end" );

    std::wstring::size_type pos = text.find( start );
    pos = ( pos == std::wstring::npos ? 0 : pos + start.size() );

    std::wstring::size_type n = text.rfind( end );

    n = ( n == std::wstring::npos || n < pos ? std::wstring::npos : n - pos );

    std::wcout << text.substr( pos, n ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ABCDEF
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage of not using boost?

Comment: @user2028058 It is simply a very bad idea to use third party lobraries instead of standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

Regex works for you. The following is a sample.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string data("begin data begin data end begin data end"), begin("begin"), end("end");
    boost::regex r(begin + "(.*)" + end);
    boost::smatch result;

    if (boost::regex_search(data, result, r)){
        std::cout << "data: " << result[1] << "\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage of using regex search instead of find f-ns? How do you think performance is affected?

Comment: You can have a test. In my opinon, regex is definitely slower. But it is more flexiable and readable. It depends on your needs. In fact, boost::regex is quite effective.

Comment: Sure, I'll test it. I think it would be slower as well.. The performance is a priority, since both of the codes do the job